# How to realize rowToggle in primefaces 3.3?

Tags: datatable, primefaces

I'm now using primefaces 3.3, but this version doesn't support `event="rawToggle"` for datatable. So I chose to use the `onExpandStart` instead of `rowToggle`, but I met with another problem. Here I want to put another datatable as the expanded row, so everytime I toggle one row in `nodetable`, I need to pass the `nodeId` of that row to `backingbean` to get all the contents of that node. If I have `event="rowToggle`", I can do it without any problem! But if I use the attribute `onExpandStart` of the dataTable, I cannot get the `somenode.nodeId` in the `backingbean`, anyone knows how to solve it?
I've also tried to put a hidden input tag `<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="#{somenode.nodeId}"/>` inside the `rowToggler`, but the value I get in `backingbean` is null.
Have been worked on it for several days, but still no ideas. Help please please please!

```xml
<p:dataTable id="nodetable" value="#{nodeedit.list}" var="somenode"
             styleClass="datatable" editable="true" 
             onExpandStart="#{nodeedit.toggle(somenode.nodeId)}" >
   <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{nodeedit.save('node')}"/>

       <p:column style="width:4%">
          <p:rowToggler>
             <h:form>
               <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="#{somenode.nodeId}"/>
             </h:form>
          </p:rowToggler>
       </p:column> 

       <p:column>
          <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
             <h:form>
                <h:commandLink action="nodeedit">#{somenode.norder}</h:commandLink>
             </h:form>
       </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="Name">
           <p:cellEditor> 
              <f:facet name="output"> 
                <h:outputText value="#{somenode.title}" /> 
              </f:facet> 
              <f:facet name="input"> 
                 <p:inputTextarea value="#{somenode.title}" style="width:100%"/> 
              </f:facet> 
           </p:cellEditor> 
       </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="Edit" style="width:50px"> 
           <p:rowEditor /> 
       </p:column>

       <p:rowExpansion>
               <p:dataTable id="contentId" var="content" 
                            value="#{nodeedit.contents}" id="contents" editable="true"> 
                  <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{nodeedit.save('content')}"/>

                  <p:column headerText="Text" style="width:450px"> 
                     <p:cellEditor> 
                        <f:facet name="output"> 
                            <h:outputText value="#{content.text}" escape="false" /> 
                        </f:facet> 
                        <f:facet name="input"> 
                            <p:inputTextarea value="#{content.text}" style="width:100%"/> 
                        </f:facet> 
                     </p:cellEditor> 
                   </p:column> 

                   <p:column headerText="Edit" style="width:50px"> 
                      <p:rowEditor /> 
                   </p:column> 

          </p:dataTable> 
       </p:rowExpansion>
  </p:dataTable>
```

I have also tried another way. The Content of a Node is also an object, in the Node Class I have defined

```java
       List<LibContent> contents = new ArrayList<LibContent>();
```

so, like what siebzOr said, I wrote in my jsf something like:

```xml
    <p:rowExpansion>
         <p:dataTable var="content" value="#{somenode.content}">

            **<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{nodeedit.save()}"/>**

            <p:column>
               <h:outputText value="#{content.someValue}" />
            </p:column>

            <!-- Other columns -->

         </p:dataTable>
    </p:rowExpansion>
```

and in backingbean nodeedit, I have

```java
        public void save() {
            for (Content content : node.contents)
                  System.out.println("content.text");
        }
```

I found that the content.text never changed no matter what I did in the page. But if I define `List<Content> contents = new ArrayList<Content>()` directly in `nodeedit`, it can get the new value!! That's why I tried to get the `nodeId` everytime I toggle the node-table and then update the contents in `backingbean`. Did I do something wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

`p:rowExpansion` is dynamic and loads it's data using AJAX. Something like this should work:

```xml
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable value="#{nodeedit.list}" var="somenode" styleClass="datatable">
        <p:column>
            <p:rowToggler />
        </p:column>

        <!-- Your columns here -->

        <p:rowExpansion>
            <p:dataTable var="content" value="#{nodeedit.contentOf(somenode)}">

                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{content.someValue}" />
                </p:column>

                <!-- Other columns -->

            </p:dataTable>
        </p:rowExpansion>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

In your backing bean you should have a method to get the content of a node, in my example `contentOf(Node node)`

```java
@Named // or @ManagedBean
@ViewScoped // or some other scope
public class Nodeedit
{
    private List<Node> list;

    //Getters and Setters

    public List<SomeClass> contentOf(Node node)
    {
        // get and return the content of the node
    }
}
```

If your `Node` has a method to get the `Content` you can do something like this in stead:

```xml
<p:rowExpansion>
    <p:dataTable var="content" value="#{somenode.content}">

        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{content.someValue}" />
        </p:column>

        <!-- Other columns -->

    </p:dataTable>
</p:rowExpansion>
```

If a `Node`'s content isn't a `Collection` of some sort I'm not sure it will work in a `p:dataTable` as the value.

I don't know what your classes look like so the above is just an idea.

Note also that I have put a `h:form` around the `p:dataTable` in stead of putting multiple forms in the `p:dataTable` itself. This is needed for multiple things like AJAX, selection, etc. You cannot nest forms.

Comment: Hi siebzOr, thanks for your reply! Your understanding is totally right! The node's content is also an object and I do have a method to get node.contents in the Class of Node. I've tried your second method, to get the contents through "somenode.contents", but the problem is that when I edit the row in content-table, the backingbean cannot get the new value. My backingbean is called NodeEdit. I once wrote an ajax: <p:ajax event="rowEdit" actionListen="#{nodeedit.save()}"/> in content-table, but all the values I got in save() were the old ones. I don't know how to solve it...

Comment: @user1453951 I believe that's another question. Since this question is about "How to realize rowToggle".

Comment: @siebzOr hummm,you're right! May be I should change the title into "how to embed an editable table in another editable table"...Ok, I'll create a new post, and if you have any idea, please let me know let me know!Thanks.